# ¿No crees que esto lo hubiera podido hacer/pudiera haber sido hecho/lo pudiese hacer un alienígena? (SUBJUNCTIVE)

Tags: traducción, gramática, subjuntivo

- ¿No crees que esto lo hubiera podido hacer un alienígena? (=>pluperfect subjunctive)
- ¿No crees que esto pudiera haber sido hecho por un no-alienígena? (=>pretérito pluscuamperfecto de subjuntivo)
- ¿No crees que esto lo pudiese hacer alguien que no sea alienígena? (=>pretérito imperfecto del subjuntivo)

---

- Don't you think this couldn't have been done by someone **other than** an alien(negative statement)
- Don't you reckon this couldn't have done by someone **who's not** an alien.
- Don't you reckon this wasn't done by someone **who wasn't** an alien(pasado de indicativo).
- Don't you reckon this wasn't done by someone **who isn't** an alien(presente de indicativo).

---

- a) Don't you think this couldn't have been done by someone **who can't be** an alien.
- b) Don't you reckon this could have been done by someone **who weren't** an alien. (past subjunctive)
- c) Don't you reckon this couldn't have done by someone **who be not** an alien. (Present subjunctive)

Does it make any difference if you say "who is" or "who was" in English? In Spanish «creer» in the negative demands SUBJUNCTIVE mood. What do you think?
I would like to know what is the correct way to translate it in the 2nd part of the sentence. Which one is better in English a) «who can't be», b) «who weren't» or c) «who be not»?

Thanks =)

Comment: *no creer* generally uses subjunctive in its subordinate clauses.  *creer* often uses subjunctive in subordinate clauses when used in interrogatives (dialect depending, somewhat).  But you've not bolded the verb that is affected by *(no) creer*, so I'm not sure what your question is exactly

Comment: I would like to know what is the correct way to translate it in the 2nd part of the sentence

Comment: That doesn't really have anything to do with *creer* though.  All three bolded bits are fine.  Why do you think one or another is better / worse?

Comment: Really I don't know. So which one is better in English?

Comment: You cannot say someone is ..... people in English but really that is off-topic here and better on an English site.

Comment: Closing this question because it is about the English language, not about the Spanish language. You might get answers if you ask on [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) or on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Latino people is an insult.

Comment: That's no insult to me and I hope I didn't offend nobody. I apologize if the question is not clear. Thank you.

Comment: @Lambie And how is it an insult? You seem to be quite good about throwing around accusations without basis. I for one am not insulted by it at all, and I'm a member of the group. Cocteau: although it's more common to just say Latinos or Hispanics, there's nothing wrong with what you said.

Comment: @Cocteau **None** of a, b or c work, IMHO (native English speaker)